# Падение скорости на сетевой карте в Linux

Tags: linux, сеть, fedora

имеется Fedora 37. Две сетевые карты. Одна от провайдера, здесь все нормально, другая раздает интернет в локальную (домашнюю сеть). На второй карте в 100 мб непредсказуемо скорость падает до минимальной, 0.16 мб, около этого. Проводил действия, менял интерфейсный кабель до роутера, подставлял ноут напрямую без роутера, переставлял карту в другой слот, менял сетевую карту(обе realtek 10/100 Мб). Ничего не помогает. После того как делаю ifdown/ifup интерфеса сетевого скорость восстанавливается на некоторое не предсказуемое время в районе 60-100 Мб.
Результат выполнение комнады на интерфейс # ethtool enp6s1

```
Settings for enp6s1:
Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  100baseT/Full
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                     100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Auto-negotiation: on
Port: MII
PHYAD: 32
Transceiver: internal
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                           drv probe link
Link detected: yes
```

Кто сталкивался с такими чудесами и знает как помочь?

Answer (score 1):

решилась проблема добавлением в параметры ядра (/etc/default/grub)

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=UUID=9a3201c6-0cc6-4ddb-9cde-701d552f78d quiet noirqdebug irqpoll"
```